# No lightning calendar on pc for Thunderbird 3.1 but available on my net-book

Tags: thunderbird, calendar

I am a recent convert to Linux and delighted that Thunderbird 3.1 is available in Ubuntu 11.04, but I can't install the excellent Lightning calendar add-on which I find so useful onto my desktop pc [on Thunderbird/About Thundebird, the set is 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110424 Thunderbird/3.1.10'].

Confusingly, my net-book which also runs exactly the same software has Lightning as part of Thunderbird [my notebook set up is Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110424 Lighning/1.Ob2 Thunderbird/3.1.10'], so why can't I get the add-on for my desktop?

Any help appreciated.
Andy T

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message? Describe what you do to try to install it and what happens.

Comment: This is generally caused by trying to install the version from addons.mozilla.org which is a 32 bit binary on a 64 bit system.  Unlike most addons, this one has a binary component.  We provide Lightning as a package (xul-ext-lightning) in Ubuntu for this reason.  I give instructions below on how to add it to your system.

Answer (score 1):

Simply search for lightning calendar in Software Center (it's xul-ext-lightning) and install it.  Restart thunderbird and you're set.

Comment: Micahg,did as instructed and works a treat - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Thunderbird in the Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Open Accessories;Terminal and enter the following command.

sudo apt-get update

3 . Close the Terminal

4 . Reinstall Thunderbird in the Ubuntu Software Center making sure that the Xul-ext-lightning box is Checked.